# A* Path Finder (Java) is inefficient using a 1024 multidimentional array

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, a-star

I have the below code for a A* pathfinder, however it is taking upwards of 10 minutes to find a solution using a simple 1024 x 1024 array.

I had to comment out //Collections.sort(this.openList); as it was throwing a comparison method violates its general contract! error when running.

Is the algorithm correct and any idea why the bottleneck? Some people using C++ are getting a response time of 40ms, not 10+ mins!

When using the `maze` array it does it in the blink of an eye, but thats using something like a 14x10 array, rather than 1024 from the `collisionMap`.

Is the method flawed in some way? Or using the wrong data structures?

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.Console;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class AStarTwo {

    // Closed list, open list and calculatedPath lists
    private final List<Node> openList;
    private final List<Node> closedList;
    private final List<Node> calcPath;

    // Collision Map to store tha map in
    private final int[][] collisionMap;

    // Current node the  program is executing
    private Node currentNode;

    // Define the start and end coords
    private final int xstart;
    private final int ystart;
    private int xEnd, yEnd;

    // Node class 
    static class Node implements Comparable {
        public Node parent;
        public int x, y;
        public double g;
        public double h;
        Node(Node parent, int xpos, int ypos, double g, double h) {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.x = xpos;
            this.y = ypos;
            this.g = g;
            this.h = h;
       }

       // Compare f value (g + h)
       @Override
       public int compareTo(Object o) {
           Node that = (Node) o;
           return (int)((this.g + this.h) - (that.g + that.h));
       }
   }

    // construct and initialise 
    public AStarTwo(int[][] collisionMap, int xstart, int ystart) {
        this.openList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.closedList = new ArrayList<>();
        this.calcPath = new ArrayList<>();
        this.collisionMap = collisionMap;
        this.currentNode = new Node(null, xstart, ystart, 0, 0);
        this.xstart = xstart;
        this.ystart = ystart;

    }

    // returns a List<> of nodes to target
    public List<Node> findPathTo(int xTo, int yTo) {

        this.xEnd = xTo;
        this.yEnd = yTo;

        // Add this to the closed list
        this.closedList.add(this.currentNode);

        // Add neighbours to openList for iteration
        addNeigborsToOpenList();

        // Whilst not at our target
        while (this.currentNode.x != this.xEnd || this.currentNode.y != this.yEnd) {

            // If nothing in the open list then return with null - handled in error message in main calling func
            if (this.openList.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
            }

            // get the lowest f value and add it to the closed list, f calculated when neighbours are sorted
            this.currentNode = this.openList.get(0);
            this.openList.remove(0); 
            this.closedList.add(this.currentNode); 

            addNeigborsToOpenList();

        }

        // add this node to the calculated path
        this.calcPath.add(0, this.currentNode);

        while (this.currentNode.x != this.xstart || this.currentNode.y != this.ystart) {

            this.currentNode = this.currentNode.parent;

            this.calcPath.add(0, this.currentNode);

        }

        return this.calcPath;
    }



    // Searches the current list for neighbouring nodes returns bool
    private static boolean checkNeighbourHasBeenSearched(List<Node> array, Node node) {
        return array.stream().anyMatch((n) -> (n.x == node.x && n.y == node.y));
    }


    // Calculate distance from current node to the target
    private double distance(int dx, int dy) {
        return Math.hypot(this.currentNode.x + dx - this.xEnd, this.currentNode.y + dy - this.yEnd); // return hypothenuse
    }

    // Add neighbouring nodes to the open list to iterate through next
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void addNeigborsToOpenList() {

        Node node;

        for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++) {

            for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++) {

                node = new Node(this.currentNode, this.currentNode.x + x, this.currentNode.y + y, this.currentNode.g, this.distance(x, y));

                // if we are not on the current node
                if ((x != 0 || y != 0) 
                    && this.currentNode.x + x >= 0 && this.currentNode.x + x < this.collisionMap[0].length // check collision map boundaries
                    && this.currentNode.y + y >= 0 && this.currentNode.y + y < this.collisionMap.length
                    && this.collisionMap[this.currentNode.y + y][this.currentNode.x + x] != -1) { // check if tile is walkable (-1)

                    // and finally check we haven't already searched the nodes
                    if(!checkNeighbourHasBeenSearched(this.openList, node) && !checkNeighbourHasBeenSearched(this.closedList, node)){
                        node.g = node.parent.g + 1.; // Horizontal/vertical cost = 1.0
                        node.g += collisionMap[this.currentNode.y + y][this.currentNode.x + x]; // add movement cost for this square


                        // Add diagonal movement cost sqrt(hor_cost² + vert_cost²) + 0.4
                        if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
                            node.g += .4;   
                        }

                        // Add the node to the List<>
                        this.openList.add(node);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        // sort in ascending order
        //Collections.sort(this.openList);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] maze = 
            { {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
              {1,0,-1,0,-1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
              {1,0,-1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
              {1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
              {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1},
              {1,0,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,0,0,0,-1},
              {1,0,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,-1,-1,-1,0,-1},
              {1,0,1,0,-1,-1,-1,0,1,0,-1,0,-1},
              {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
              {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1}

            };

        // Define the size of the grid
        final int sizeOf = 20;

        int[][] collisionMap = new int[sizeOf][];

        for(int i=0;i < sizeOf; i++) {
            // -1 = blocked
            // 0+ = cost
            collisionMap[i] = new int[sizeOf];
        }

        // set the value of the nodes
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeOf; k++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sizeOf; j++) {
                if(j == 30 && k < 100) {
                    collisionMap[k][j] = -1;
                } else if (j == 50 && k > 230) {
                    collisionMap[k][j] = -1;
                }else {
                    collisionMap[k][j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }        

        AStarTwo as = new AStarTwo(maze, 9, 9);
        List<Node> path = as.findPathTo(0,0);

        if(path == null) {
            System.out.println("Unable to reach target");
        }


        // create image buffer to write output to
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(sizeOf, sizeOf, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // Set colours
        int r = 255;
        int g = 0;
        int b = 0; 

        int colRed = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        r = 0;
        g = 255;
        b = 0; 

        int colGreen = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        r = 0;
        g = 0;
        b = 255; 

        int colBlue = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        r = 255;
        g = 255;
        b = 255; 

        int colWhite = (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        if (path != null) {

            path.forEach((n) -> {
                System.out.print("[" + n.x + ", " + n.y + "] ");
                maze[n.y][n.x] = 2;
            });

            for (int[] maze_row : maze) {
                for (int maze_entry : maze_row) {
                    switch (maze_entry) {

                        // normal tile
                        case 0:
                            img.setRGB(j, i, colWhite);
                            break;

                        // final path
                        case 2:
                            img.setRGB(j, i, colBlue);
                            break;

                        // Object to avoid
                        case -1:
                            img.setRGB(j, i, colRed);
                            break;

                        // Any other value
                        default:
                            img.setRGB(j, i, colWhite);
                    }

                    j++;
                }
                // count j - reset as if it were a for loop
                if(i != 12) {
                    j=0;
                }
                i++;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        // output file
        File f = new File("aStarPath.png");

        try {
            ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", f);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("i: " + i + ", j: " + j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your 'compareTo' method is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is this line:

```
return array.stream().anyMatch((n) -> (n.x == node.x && n.y == node.y));
```

which is called around O(n^2) times and will take time proportional to the size of the array (which will also be O(n^2) in the worst case for a n by n maze).

You want a faster method of performing this test.

For example:

1. Use a set to hold the open and closed lists instead of list
2. Or use an extra field in the node structure to indicate if it is in the open or closed list

Comment: Thank you, I actually changed this for both your suggestions, I used set and had a bool value to indicate the lists - very helpful, cheers!